# First Rails Project: Rake Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm running rails on Mac OS X. I think I installed it correctly, but I'm getting the following error.

```
$ rake db:create
(in /Users/user_name/myapp)
rake aborted!
Could not find RubyGem mocha (>= 0)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What is the problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're missing the mocha gem.  Running `sudo gem install mocha` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
sudo rake gems:install
```

So it will go through your environment.rb to see which gems are depended upon and install them.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think him seeing that error message means it's not in the environment file.  I think it it's in the environment file, it says "run rake gems:install" in the error message.